# how to disable default keyboard? i want only the custom keyboard to be displayed in my webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

When i click/focus on a textbox i get two keyboards popping up and hides the whole screen, but i want only my custom keyboard to be displayed in my page.

I think the solution would be preventing the android-soft keyboard to popup or disabling it.

I tried giving `event.stopImmediatepropogation()` and `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the second keyboard from appearing but it didn't work.

Can anyone help me to prevent the android soft-keyboard from showing up.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution

I added "readonly required" to the element and it solved the problem

`<input type="text" readonly required>`